# Solspace tag incorrect number of entries returned

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I'm using tags as a filter example here: http:// devsite2 . desworkdev . co . uk/selector (Test site). The number of products with a specific tag is show next to each tag name.

On certain tags, when I click through the number of products shown doesn't match. E.g. semi sweet (6) should have 6 products with that tag, however when I click through only 5 products are showing.

Could someone please let me know what could be causing this?

**UPDATE:**

- ExpressionEngine v2.9.0
- Tag 4.2.7

Code on the tag list page

```
{exp:tag:cloud channel="products" tag_group_name="default" limit="100"}
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="{websafe_tag}"> <a href="{path='selector/tag'}/{websafe_tag}">{tag} ({total_entries})</a></li>
{/exp:tag:cloud}
```

Code on the tag entry page

```
{exp:tag:entries inclusive="yes" sort="asc"}
<div class="box3col">
     {if no_tag_results}
        <h2>No products match your tag selection</h2>
     {/if}

     <a href="{url_title_path='products/detail'}">
     {if new_product !=""}
         <span class="new"><img src="{site_url}images/interface/new.png" alt="New product" /></span>
     {/if}
     {if image_1 !=""}
            <img src="{image_1}" alt="" />
     {if:else}
            <img src="{site_url}images/uploads/default.jpg" alt="" />
     {/if}
     </a>
     <div class="copare-code-wrapper">
           <div class="prod-code"><p>Product code</p>{if recipe_code !=""}{recipe_code}{if:else}N/A{/if}</div>
     </div>
     <div class="info light">
         <h2>{title}</h2><p><a href="{url_title_path='products/detail'}">More info</a></p>
     </div>
</div>
{/exp:tag:entries}
```

URL: http://devsite2.desworkdev.co.uk/selector/tag/semi+sweet

Comment: What version of Tag and EE are you using? Can you show us the template code? (things often depend on how things are coded, not just for Tag btw) Also, can you show us how the URL looks like when you select your "semi sweet (6)" link?

Comment: @Deswork - please revise your question when asked for clarification, rather than adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realised some products have a highlight status so I needed to add the status parameter to {exp:tag:entries inclusive="yes" status="highlight|open" sort="asc"}